# How to resolve 'User <anonymous> has insufficient permission to access EJB' even though correct user is specified in InitialContext

Tags: java, tomcat, weblogic12c

I have a client app that runs as a servlet on Apache Tomcat connecting to either a WildFly 10.1 or a WebLogic 12c application server. The application was recently ported from JBoss 6.1 and WebLogic 11g to work on these newer application servers. The application is working as expected when using WildFly 10.1, but I keep getting 'User  has insufficient permissions to access EJB' when it tries to communicate with the main application running on WebLogic 12c.

I did come across an Oracle reference regarding JNDI Contexts and Threads, saying that users are associated with threads, and another reference that mentioned there was a change in behaviour in WebLogic 9.0 removing
support for a VM-wide default user, and that you must be in the same thread (or a child thread) in order for the authentication to work.

I was able to write a simple test client that confirms this behaviour. If I instantiate my InitialContext in one thread, but then try to use it in another thread, I get the 'User ' error. If I try again, but this time instantiating the InitialContext in the main application, I am able to successfully communicated with the application server through the main application, as well as any other threads that I create.

Here is the sample test client that replicates the error:

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.ejb.FinderException;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

import com.supportsoft.encore.inventory.dto.DeviceDTO;
import com.supportsoft.encore.inventory.ejb.InventoryInterfaceFactory;
import com.supportsoft.encore.inventory.ejb.remote.DeviceManager;
import com.supportsoft.encore.system.exception.RealmViolationException;

public class GetInitialContextThreaded {
    private static InitialContext ic;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            // Use a thread to initialize the initial context
            Thread thread1 = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    log("THREAD1: Getting InitialContext.");
                    Properties icProps = new Properties();
                    icProps.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "weblogic.jndi.WLInitialContextFactory");
                    icProps.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "t3://localhost:6002");
//                  icProps.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");
//                  icProps.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "http-remoting://localhost:7777");
                    icProps.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "system");
                    icProps.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "system");

//                   icProps.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", false);
//                   icProps.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");
//                   icProps.put("jboss.naming.client.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS", "false");
//                   icProps.put("jboss.naming.client.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOPLAINTEXT", "false");

                    icProps.put("java.naming.factory.url.pkgs", "weblogic.jndi.factories:weblogic.corba.j2ee.naming.url");
//                  icProps.put("weblogic.jndi.enableDefaultUser", "true");

                    try {
                        ic = new InitialContext(icProps);
                        log("THREAD1: Have InitialContext.");
                    } catch (NamingException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
            thread1.start();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Test connection
            log("MAIN: Testing connection to app server.");
            InventoryInterfaceFactory iFactory = getInventoryInterfaceFactory(ic, "MAIN");

            log("MAIN: Getting DeviceManager handle");
            DeviceManager devMgr = iFactory.getDeviceManager();
            log("MAIN: Have DeviceManager handle");

            log("MAIN: Get device");
            DeviceDTO device = devMgr.getByID(1000L);
            log("MAIN: Have device");


            Thread thread2 = new Thread() {
                public void run() {
                    log("THREAD2: Testing connection to app server.");
                    InventoryInterfaceFactory iFactory = getInventoryInterfaceFactory(ic, "THREAD2");

                    try {
                        log("THREAD2: Getting DeviceManager handle");
                        DeviceManager devMgr = iFactory.getDeviceManager();
                        log("THREAD2: Have DeviceManager handle");

                        log("THREAD2: Get device");
                        DeviceDTO device = devMgr.getByID(1000L);
                        log("THREAD2: Have device");
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
            thread2.start();

            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            log("MAIN: Successfully connected to app server.");

        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FinderException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (RealmViolationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static InventoryInterfaceFactory getInventoryInterfaceFactory(InitialContext ctx, String logPrefix) {
        InventoryInterfaceFactory factory = null;
        try {
            log(logPrefix + ": Instantiating factory");
                factory = InventoryInterfaceFactory.getInstance(ctx);
            log(logPrefix + ": Instantiated factory");

        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        return factory;


    }

    private static void log(String message) {
        SimpleDateFormat time_formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss.SSS z yyyy");
        String current_time_str = time_formatter.format(System.currentTimeMillis());
        System.out.println(current_time_str + ": " + message);
    }

}
```

And here is the output that I see when I run it:

```
Tue Oct 22 15:34:35.395 ADT 2019: THREAD1: Getting InitialContext.
Tue Oct 22 15:34:37.469 ADT 2019: THREAD1: Have InitialContext.
Tue Oct 22 15:34:40.371 ADT 2019: MAIN: Testing connection to app server.
Tue Oct 22 15:34:40.372 ADT 2019: MAIN: Instantiating factory
Tue Oct 22 15:34:40.401 ADT 2019: MAIN: Instantiated factory
Tue Oct 22 15:34:40.402 ADT 2019: MAIN: Getting DeviceManager handle
Tue Oct 22 15:34:40.580 ADT 2019: MAIN: Have DeviceManager handle
Tue Oct 22 15:34:40.580 ADT 2019: MAIN: Get device
Exception in thread "main" javax.ejb.EJBAccessException: [EJB:010160]Security violation: User <anonymous> has insufficient permission to access EJB type=<ejb>, application=xyz, module=xyz-impl.jar, ejb=XYZManagerBean, method=getByID, methodInterface=Remote, signature={java.lang.Long}.
    at weblogic.utils.StackTraceDisabled.unknownMethod()
```

It is fairly straight forward to resolve this in my test client, as I mentioned above, by having the main application instantiate the InitialContext.

My problem is how to handle this in a servlet deployed and running on Apache Tomcat. When the application starts up, the initialize() method does a number of things such as load properties files, instantiate the InitialContext, and test the connection to the application server. That all works fine. The problem is when the servlet starts processing a new request and tries to communicate with the WebLogic 12c application server. It is at this point that I get the 'User ' error.

Is there a way to configure Tomcat or the servlet so that the InitialContext can be shared between the servlet threads without "losing" the authenticated principal? In WebLogic 11g we included a context property called "weblogic.jndi.enableDefaultUser" and set it to "true", but that does not appear to be supported in WebLogic 12c.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Trying to answer as this could be useful for someone looking for an answer.

Do you see this issue happening at the server Startup?
If yes, then pls pass Principle name in the Weblogic descriptor file

Just For ex

XXX.YYYY.CREATE.PRINCIPAL

Comment: <create-as-principal-name id="xxx_create_principle">YYYY.CREATE.PRINCIPAL</create-as-principal-name>